# Cannot receive push notification using onCreate event in firebase reail time database

Tags: typescript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to achive the next feature:
I want to send a Push Notification to my device, when I add a record in my firebase real time database.

I registered my device at firebase, I have sent a test Push Notification via Firebase Console - I receive the Push Notification on my device.

But now, when I deploy the next function the firebase and try to add a record under `/user-chat` path - I do not receive any push notifcation. Why? How to debug/test this?

The code is below:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database
  .ref('/user-chat')
  .onCreate((event: any) => {

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Title',
            body: 'come check it',
            badge: '0',
            sound: 'default',
        }
    };

    const token = 'myTestedVerifiedToken';

    return admin
      .messaging()
      .sendToDevice(token, payload)
      .then((response: any) => {
          // 
      });
  });
```

**UPDATE:**
I have suceeded to send the Push Notification direct to my device locally using nodejs. But now, when I wrap it to the onCreate method and try to deploy it, using `firebase deploy` command - I receive the next error:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './cargo-tender-firebase-adminsdk-8e307-c6b82762d2.json'
```

What is the problem? The path works when I run the script locally.
Here is the code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = require('./cargo-tender-firebase-adminsdk-8e307-c6b82762d2.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://cargo-tender.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database
  .ref('/user-chat')
  .onCreate((event: any) => {

    const payload = {
        notification: {
        title: 'Title',
        body: 'come check it',
        badge: '0',
        sound: 'default',
        }
    };
    return admin
      .messaging()
      .sendToDevice('fcI1JGvOQnI:APA91bFql_J3Vx3TEfJgO6cwk6nmHBLtVrRk1J3AjD6f3nr5F5ZAI2yAy2Iiz4zBpkIXET2WurO8cjU0PY9lUbrPtNkej_oDCzozwIx1y_CwHxre1f3rFvIzr5K414oqBHdkamA2249e', payload)
  });
```

Comment: You might want to start by running a simple Node.js script locally that sends a message with `admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...)`. If you can't get that the work, it definitely won't work in Cloud Functions either. Once you have it working locally, you can start adding the database trigger.

Comment: I cannot setup it locally, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768174/warning-firebase-config-and-gcloud-project-environment-variables-are-missing-i

Comment: I have succeed to send push notification locally, direct to the device, but now, when I try to deploy a bit modified code, I receive an error: `Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './cargo-tender-firebase-adminsdk-8e307-c6b82762d2.json'`. I've added the code to the thread

Comment: ok, I fixed this error, by moving the .json file one folder up, and setting path to `../cargo-tender-firebase-adminsdk-8e307-c6b82762d2.json` (double `..` in front), but the push notifications aren't still working

Comment: Fixed, this, I have to change the path to `.ref('/user-chat/{anything}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I had to move service account .json file out of the src file and change the path to it in the script like to parent folder (double dots `..`)

2) I had to change ref path to `.ref('/user-chat/{anything}')`